# How to use like Clause in C# LInQ

Tags: c#, linq

How would I use a like clause using the following LINQ snippet?:

```
var query = from r in document.Descendants("Employee")
                        where (string)r.Element("FirstName").Value == txtSearch.Text
                        select new
                        {

                            FirstName = r.Element("FirstName").Value,
                            Age = r.Element("Age").Value
                        };
```

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
var query = from r in document.Descendants("Employee")
                        where (string)r.Element("FirstName").Value.Contains(txtSearch.Text)
                        select new
                        {

                            FirstName = r.Element("FirstName").Value,
                            Age = r.Element("Age").Value
                        };
```

...thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: Please describe **how** *"it did not work"*

Comment: I get the following error: Cannot convert type 'bool' to 'string

Comment: ... the error is generates at this line:  where (string)r.Element("FirstName").Value.Contains(txtSearch.Text)

Comment: Well that seems like a fairly straight forward error message, right? `Contains` returns a `bool`, and you're trying to cast it to a `string`. You should leave it as a bool, since that's what a `Where` clause needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to cast a boolean to an string:

```
where (string)r.Element("FirstName").Value.Contains(txtSearch.Text)
```

If Value really needs a cast to String the code should be this:

```
where ((string)r.Element("FirstName").Value).Contains(txtSearch.Text)
```

But I think you don't need it because if VS has completed `Contains` it's an string function and the cast isn't needed:

```
where r.Element("FirstName").Value.Contains(txtSearch.Text)
```